# How organize questions and answers in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to build a good structure of 'questions and answers' in my SQL (Azure) server.
I'm thinking in do this way:

```
table question
    id float (we could have lots of questions, so that's why float and don't int)
    nvarchar question (question can vary in size of characters)
    id_answer float

table answer
    id float
    nvarchar answer
```

Is this a good way in your opinion ?
I have to think about different kind of questions, I could have question like these :

```
question: Who invented the lamp ?
answer:   Thomas Edson

question: Thomas Edson invested the lamp ?
answer: No. (true or false)
```

Do you guys know some other good way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an order to questions?  Are questions part of something larger, e.g. surveys?  Are some yes/no, multiple choice, numeric, or essay?  Do you care who answered the questions, when, and how often?  Might the questions change over time or be retired?  Is `BIGINT` inadequate for identifications?

Comment: @HABO There's an order in the questions, yes, there's some questions with yes and no, yes I care who answered the question, the question can be added but not changed over time, to mantain the integrity of the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I did a Q & A system it handled surveys that consisted of multiple pages of questions.  Answers could be checkboxes, radio buttons or a select box for multiple choice, or text input (optionally limited to integer values).

The tables looked something like this:

```
-- There are pages of questions.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pages] (
    [PageId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Description] [varchar] (1024) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [PageTypeId] [int] NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageTypes] (
    [PageTypeId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Name] [varchar] (32) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Description] [varchar] (1024) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TargetPages] (
    [QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [PageId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Rank] [int] NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Questions have input fields.  Perhaps a text entry, perhaps several multiple-guess choices.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (
    [QuestionId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [Description] [varchar] (1024) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Filespec] [varchar] (128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fields] (
    [QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [FieldName] [varchar] (64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [InputTypeId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [Description] [varchar] (256) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InputTypes] ( -- Roughly: checkbox, radio button, text, textarea or select list.
    [InputTypeId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [InputTypeName] [varchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Choices] [bit] NOT NULL ,
    [NumericValue] [bit] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Choices] ( -- Defines radio button or select list choices for multiple choice questions.
    [FieldId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [cName] [varchar] (64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [cValue] [varchar] (64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL ,
    [Rank] [int] NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Then we have the answers supplied by users.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Inquiries] ( 
    [InquiryId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [dTimestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
    [ResponseSequence] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [Username] [varchar] (16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Responses] ( -- Multiple choice.
    [InquiryId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldValue] [varchar] (1024) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IntegerResponses] ( -- User supplied integer or multiple choice value.
-- NB: Checkbox values are handled thusly: a row here indicates the box was checked, no row is unchecked.  The value is meaningless.
    [InquiryId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldValue] [int] NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TextResponses] ( -- User supplied text.
    [InquiryId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldId] [int] NOT NULL ,
    [FieldValue] [varchar] (1024) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL 
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
exec sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'1 ==> Values are in the   Choices   table.', N'user', N'dbo', N'table', N'InputTypes', N'column', N'Choices'
GO
exec sp_addextendedproperty N'MS_Description', N'1 ==> Values are numeric.', N'user', N'dbo', N'table', N'InputTypes', N'column', N'NumericValue'
GO
```

The queries kept running into the limit on the number of tables allowed in a `SELECT`, 256 or so.

Answer (score 1):

I would definatly NOT go for a float, since it is a non-precise and non-deterministic data type. Try to use a bigint in stead.
A float is very hard to put into an index as far as i know. Don't know about sql databases (azure) and/or sql server 2012 though

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your questions are going to be structured.

If you have free text entry, with a single correct answer, then it makes no sense to separate Questions from Answers, so have an Answer field in the question table. But then you rely on correct spelling, etc.

If you plan on having multiple choice answers to a question, then you'd want to have the QuestionID in the Answers table, as opposed to your setup above.

You could additionally have a table between Questions and Answers so an Answer could be an Answer to more than one Question.

And your IDs want to be ints, not floats; if you exceed the range of ints, use uniqueidentifiers. Floats aren't *precise*

Comment: As for the IDs, a `bigint` certainly also is worth mentioning, uses half the size of the `uniqueidentifier` and the range is certainly big enough (2^63).

Comment: I meant int in the general sense, but I doubt that there will even be 2^32 questions :)

Comment: Sure, I also don't expect more than 2^31 questions (assuming that no negative IDs shall be used).

Comment: @podiluska It makes sense, at least to me, separate question from answer, for now, would not be question like wrong and right, the answer can vary, actually my form is a form about 'operational procedure' in my company.
And thanks about the float thing, I think I will use it then.

Comment: Do you mean the answer to a question, or the response provided by an answerer?